# Better way to handle notifications

Tags: notifications, 6.0-marshmallow, notification-bar

I am using latest android on my phone. One issue I face is that I have a lot of apps installed. Many of them generate notifications which I dont want to loose. If I leave notifications unattended for a day or two, a lot of notifications get stacked up (almost 100+). I dont want to turn off those notifications. I just want better way to handle those notifications:

- is there any way (or app) to archive notifications
- is there any way to group notification belonging to same app (so that I may decide to archive or delete all of them)
- is there any way (or app) which allows me to archive or delete all notifications at specific dates or dates older than the specified one
- For many months my phone has issue of restarting and with each restart the notifications get cleared. So I also want to know if there is any way (or app) that can periodically backup/archive notifications so even if my phones restarts I can always pull them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple items of interest in this context:

- there is a built-in functionality to access your notification history, see [How to get the notification history](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/50177/16575) for details
- there are several [apps to backup/archive notifications](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_notifications#group_1078) – e.g. [Past Notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coconuts.pastnotifications) (a notification history surviving even reboots) or [Notibox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noti)
- there are apps to [Filter/block notifications](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_notifications#group_1079)
- there are several more apps to control other aspects of notifications (same page as the last link goes to)

Still, I'm not sure there's a way to control aspects 2 and 3 of your list (group apps,<sup>**1**</sup> delete by date). I've not yet encountered any app for those, so chances are rather low – but one might have slipped through my net.

---

<sup>**1:** [Nevolution](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.nevo) promises to "bundle notifications" – but it's not clear from its description if "bundles" cover multiple apps</sup>