# Unknown icon briefly appears in notifications

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, notification-icons

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out with this icon means. It's a phone with two left-pointing arrows on the right edge, and three concentric half-circles off the left edge.

It appears randomly, flashes once or twice, and is gone. It's all too quick to get a screen shot.

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 on Verizon running Android 5.0.1. I also have a Gear S2 watch connected. And my mobile hotspot is also on (currently) with a tablet connected.

Any thoughts, please??
Ed

Edit: 5/18/19
So sorry for taking so long.  Crazy work and life schedule.
I have attached a rough drawing of the mystery icon.

[image: Mystery Icon]

Edit (2):
Just found it -- it's for Samsung services (com.samsung.accessory). I'm assuming it gets called to communicate with my Gear S2 watch.

Comment: On your homescreen long prees for about 5 seconds then go to widgets tap the widget for settings then place it anywhere on you homescreen the shortcut you want is notification log. tap on the widget you made and you can see all noifications from the past few days. you can then see which app the noification came from.

Comment: @qblueRed42 -- I don't have a notifications log shortcut???

Comment: Does the icon appear on the left side (-> app notification) or the right side (-> system icon) of the notification bar?

Comment: @Robert: On the left side.

Comment: Then there is a chance: Android keeps track of recent notifications. You can see the notification history as described here: [How to get the notification history](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50177).

Comment: @Robert: As I told qblueRed42 earlier, that Notifications Log shortcut is not available on my phone. But that post did tell me there may be an app I can download to access that, so thank you for that.

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider posting it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed but even encouraged](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!