# Why whatsapp always makes notifications at the same time of everyday but there is no message?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Whatsapp always makes notifications at 13:15 of everyday, but when I check, there is no message at all. So when it's about to 13:15, I keep looking at my phone, whatsapp pops up a notification but it disappears immediately. This happens at 13:15 of everyday. I don't understand what is wrong. My phone is Android 9.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd assume it's trying to create a backup daily?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. But not everyone receives this notification everyday, right? What is wrong with my phone? How could I fix it?

Comment: Check the WhatsApp settings if the backup is set to daily. If it is, then the notification will also appear daily (though usually late night, not in the middle of noon). Depends on the amount to back up, it can be as short as 1 second and disappear after that. You can also try [How to get the notification history](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/50177/44325) to identify and pinpoint the cause first.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked the notification history, it is Whatsapp. The channelID is other_notifications@1. I don't understand what other notifications it is. I already set the backup option of whatsapp to Never long time ago.

Comment: I found some things here. I don't know whether they work or not. I have to wait until tomorrow. 1: https://www.journeybytes.com/stop-whatsapp-you-may-have-new-messages-notification/   2: https://www.journeybytes.com/stop-whatsapp-checking-for-new-messages-notification/