# What is causing Android device to turn its screen on at seemingly random times?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery-life, screen, lg, power-on

A friend has an LG phone running Android 6.0 (Marshmallow).  Many, many times during each day (and night) the device's screen apparently turns itself on.  This is causing much battery drain, and reportedly, a bit of annoyance.

There are no incoming calls or SMS messages at these times.  There are also no new notifications from Android or any installed apps when this occurs.

All apps on the device were installed from the Google Play Store or from F-Droid.  The only exception is the licensed version of AdGuard, which was purchased and downloaded directly from AdGuard.

Scanning for malware using several different well-known scanners reportedly came up with nothing.

The device is *not* rooted.

The device is stationary on a flat surface when this is noticed.  It reportedly happens regardless of whether or not the device is plugged in to a USB cable for power.

A new battery was installed, but that did not result in any changes (except longer battery life).

What could be causing this, and how to fix it?

Comment: Check the notification history? It could be a notification that only appeared and disappeared in less than 1 second.

Comment: Screen may wake up (due to full wakelock held before holding the partial one) when a scheduled job runs or an alarm is fired e.g. for a sync job or to fetch cloud messages. This - kind of buggy - behavior was more common in old Android releases. Checking `logcat` may help.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks.  Is there any way to check the notification history on Android 6?

Comment: @IrfanLatif Interesting ideas.  Thanks.  I'm trying to remember... how does one check `logcat` on Android 6?  BTW, I don't think they have a computer to help with that process, but I can certainly ask.

Comment: BTW, Andrew and Irfan, I just noticed that this question (which I posted 12 minutes ago) has 4 views, and I think SE counts the posting action as 1 view.  That means you two are 2 out of the first 3 readers, and you both posted helpful comments.  Thanks so much!

Comment: [Android 4.3: How to get the notification history](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/50177/44325) may help, but it seems it also depends on the vendor and Android version.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks Andrew. I need to get some rest, but I'll review that QA soon.

Comment: Is there data sync going on? Does your anti-virus download a new key file automatically and scan? Do you use Dropbox? Google services like Play Protect? App auto-update on?