# Summon on Samsung of bent arrow icon to the left with a number 2?

Tags: notifications

I woke up to a bent arrow pointing down to the left with a number two. I know this isn’t missed calls as it didn’t have a phone. This icon was in my notifications bar and I swiped away before I saw what it was. Has anyone came across this?

Comment: You can try to check the Android notification history: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/50177/2241

Comment: Hi, could you [edit] and clarify the title? I have a difficulty in understanding the title, particularly "summon"(?)

Answer (score 0):

It means two missed calls.  The notification bar gives a summary, not phone numbers.  Look at your call history to confirm.

Comment: There were no missed calls and it wasn’t the missed call symbol. There were no phone with the icon.